# What is the earliest history of Middle Eastern women wearing veils for modesty while in public?

Tags: ancient-history, middle-east, women, fashion

The Hebrew Bible (Tanakh, Christian Old Testament) recorded women wearing veils as early as Rebekah in Genesis (Breshith).  See [Judaism stack exchange](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26864/biblical-significance-of-face-veil)

However, there is debate over whether women wore veils in public for modesty as currently done in the Middle East.  As often the issue, historic records assumed the reader knew the customs and didn't describe the customs in detail.

Are there other ancient records (e.g. Egyptian pictures, text, cuneiform tablets, etc.) that give clearer indication of early Middle Eastern customs on wearing veils that can answer this question?

Comment: [Babylon](http://www.historycentral.com/dates/Babylonia/Women.html) and [Persia](http://www.arcgis.com/apps/MapJournal/index.html?appid=18277b7bfb394c48b77e6308a09259fc). As for [Egypt](http://www.historymuseum.ca/cmc/exhibitions/civil/egypt/egcl06e.html), the five volume *Gale Encyclopedia of Fashion, Costume, and Culture* makes little secret that transparent or see-through clothes were quite common for both sexes. I also doubt, based on comparative linguistics, that covering one's face literally referred to the frontal part of one's head, but that's somewhat speculative.

Comment: See through veils worked well with Palestinian Christian woman in the twentieth century.  During the day, you could see out, but not see in.  They covered the entire head.

Comment: "Assyrian law dictated that wives, daughters, and widows must wear a veil, but prostitutes and slave women were forbidden from wearing a veil." http://www.fashionencyclopedia.com/fashion_costume_culture/The-Ancient-World-Mesopotamia/Veils.html

Comment: *Linen could be made so thin, or sheer, that it was **transparent.** Egyptians were **not modest** and enjoyed **showing off their bodies. Women and men** are frequently **depicted in hieroglyphs,** or picture stories, wearing **see-through garments.*** (First volume, page 23).

Comment: I'm more interested in answers than points.  So, there appears to be a contrast between the Assyrians and Egyptians.

Comment: @PerryWebb: Yes. But not with regard to head or face veils. Egyptians preferred less-densely-woven clothes, and understandably so, given Africa's (much) warmer climate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Still waiting for a more complete answer, but embarrassed that the book referenced is on my computer.

> Neither wives of seigniors nor [widows] nor [Assyrian women], who go out on the street [may have] their heads [uncovered]. The daughters of a seignior … whether it is a shawl or a robe or [a mantle], must veil themselves; [they must not have] their heads [uncovered]. Whether … or … or … they must [not veil themselves, but] when they go out on the street alone, they must veil themselves. A concubine who goes out on the street with her mistress must veil herself. A sacred prostitute whom a man married must veil herself on the street, but one whom a man did not marry must have her head uncovered on the street; she must not veil herself. A harlot must not veil herself; her head must be uncovered;
> -- ("The Middle Assyrian Laws," Translator: Theophile J. Meek, Tablet A)
> Pritchard, J. B. (Ed.). (1969). The Ancient Near Eastern Texts Relating to the Old Testament  (3rd ed. with Supplement, p. 183). Princeton: Princeton University Press.

> [Dating above] The tablets themselves date from the time of Tiglath-pileser I in the 12th century B.C., but the laws on them may go back to the 15th century.
> --
> Pritchard, J. B. (Ed.). (1969). The Ancient Near Eastern Texts Relating to the Old Testament  (3rd ed. with Supplement, p. 180). Princeton: Princeton University Press.

Comment: Heads covered.  Does this indicate "head" only or "from the head down"?